# DeepCopy Object in JavaScript using immer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immer.js

I am using [immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer) to transform react/redux state. Can I also use immer to just deep copy an object without transforming it?

```
import produce, {nothing} from "immer"



const state = {
    hello: "world"
}

produce(state, draft => {})
produce(state, draft => undefined)
// Both return the original state: { hello: "world"}
```

This is from the official immer README. Does this mean that passing an empty function to `produce` returns a deep copy of the original state or actually the original state?

Thank you very much for your help :)!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is easily testable with

```
import { produce } from 'immer'

const state = {
  hello: 'world',
}

const nextState = produce(state, draft => {})

nextState.hello = 'new world'
console.log(state, nextState)
```

which outputs

```
Object { hello: "new world" }

Object { hello: "new world" }
```

which means that it does NOT create a deep copy of an object.

**UPDATE:**

So I got interested and tested out the library a lot and here are my findings.

The code snippet I wrote above is simply an optimisation in the library which returns the old state if no changes are made. However, if you make some changes, then the library starts functioning as intended and the mutation later is made impossible. That is,

```
const state = {
  hello: 'world',
}

const nextState = produce(state, draft => {
  draft.hello = 'new world';
})

nextState.hello = 'newer world';

console.log(state, nextState)
```

will result in an error: `TypeError: "world" is read-only`

Which means that your newState is immutable and you can no longer perform mutations on it.

Another rather interesting thing I found is that immer fails when using `class` instances. That is,

```
class Cls {
  prop = 10;
}

const instance = new Cls();

const obj = {
  r: instance,
};

const newObj = produce(obj, draft => {
  draft.r.prop = 15;
});

console.log(obj, newObj);
```

results in

```
r: Object { prop: 15 }

r: Object { prop: 15 }
```

---

So to get back to the initial question, can you get a deep copy of the initial Object by changing nothing in the draft. No you cannot, and even if you did (by changing a property created just to fool immer perhaps), the resultant cloned object will be immutable and not really helpful.

Comment: I had used class instance and is deep updating the state using immer. I now got my answer for why my setState is not rerendering the Application on deep updating with immer?

Comment: The class thing could be because it's missing an `[immerable] = true` property. I don't know if this feature was added after you posted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solution :
The Immer's produce only provides a new deep cloned object on updation.
you can create your own produce function that behaves just like that of immer's produce but gives a cloned object everytime using loadash

```
import _ from 'lodash';
export default function produceClone(object, modifyfunction) {
    let objectClone = _.cloneDeep(object);
    if (!modifyfunction) return objectClone;
    modifyfunction(objectClone);
    return objectClone;
    }
```

This will give you a deepCloned(or deep copied) object everytime, irrespective of whether you modify the object or not.

Comment: Just use lodash without immer here in this example, no need to do it this way why i only need a deep clone, just ``cloneDeep`` will do the job here